# HTML5 Video does not work on mobile browsers when authenticated

Tags: html, video, mobile

I'm using a standard video tag like so `<video src="test.mp4" controls>​​</video>`. I'm in a SharePoint 2013 environment with NTLM authentication with basic authentication as fall back. The video tag works without issue on all desktop browsers that support HTML5 video.

On mobile browsers, the video tag fails once I authenticate to the site. The video is just static public content that is being served by IIS 8 and is not a part of SharePoint. The only exception so far is Firefox on android, which works without issue. I've removed NTLM auth and switched to basic auth only with the same results.

I've tested so far:

- iPad iOS 8 - Safari, Chrome
- Android K & L - Chrome, Firefox
- Windows Phone 8.1 - IE

The video works as long as I am not authenticated to the host where the video is located. So, if I am at host1 with markup pointing at a video on host2, the video will work until I authenticate to host2.

The video will also work fine if I'm going through a forms based authentication. In my case, I'm using Microsoft TMG.

I've gotten this far with Android Chrome: It will first send a range request with 0-1 byte as expected with Chrome as the user agent. When unauthenticated, it will ask for the rest of the video with stagefright as the user agent. When authenticated, it doesn't send anything and simply fails to play the video. ADB logcat returns this when that happens:

> E/StagefrightMetadataRetriever(  183): Unable to instantiate an extractor for 'snipped-video-url'.
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682): Error configuring data source
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682): java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682):  at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682):  at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:105)
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682):  at org.chromium.content.browser.MediaResourceGetter.configure(MediaResourceGetter.java:417)
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682):  at org.chromium.content.browser.MediaResourceGetter.configure(MediaResourceGetter.java:259)
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682):  at org.chromium.content.browser.MediaResourceGetter.extract(MediaResourceGetter.java:153)
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682):  at org.chromium.content.browser.MediaResourceGetter.extractMediaMetadata(MediaResourceGetter.java:125)
>
> E/MediaResourceGetter(11682): Unable to configure metadata extractor
>
> I/MediaFocusControl(  744):  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager@2ff8d914org.chromium.media.MediaPlayerListener@23b9af5d
>
> D/MediaPlayer(11682): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>
> I/AwesomePlayer(  183): setDataSource_l()

My first thought was it was a Chrome/Safari issue, but IE behaving the same way makes it less likely. Is this by design? Any direction to figuring out what is going on would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

i have a issue which is same as your issue(E/StagefrightMetadataRetriever( 183): Unable to instantiate an extractor for 'snipped-video-url'.).after doing lot of work finally find the way to correct that.

add this line in the manifest of your project

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Error
[image: Error]

After Error
[image: After error]